# Kohana in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, kohana, subdirectory

I need to put Kohana 3 project to subdirectory.

Now when  I type `mysite.xyz/<subdirectory>` it run properly (default controller load ok). 
But, when I type: 
`mysite.xyz/<subdirectory>/<controller>` 
or
`mysite.xyz/subdirectory>/<controller>/<method>`
that redirect me to 
`mysite.xyz/<controller>/<method>` and fails (Not found requested url).

`<subdirectory>` = `/folder1/folder2/folder3/`

I had changed base url in kohana.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/folder3/

###### Add trailing slash (optional) ######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php/(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|media)
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you also change the `base_url` in bootstrap.php?

Comment: Yes. I have changed it to`/folder1/folder2/folder3`

Comment: if you changed the base_url pah in bootstrap than you don't need RewriteBase in .htaccess try to comment it. as Its relitive path for installation.

Comment: @zyx4sdk I don't know that you need `RewriteRule ^(.*)folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php/(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]`, and `?kohana_uri=$1` is OK? In standard KO.htaccess is `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]`